# "Half of my heart is at my hometown" What is the part of speech of "half" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In this case, half would be a noun or would it be an adjective?
I see it describing the way the heart finds itself, in half.

Answer (score 1):

There are some homonyms with this form /noun, adjective, adverb, numeral, pre-determiner, pronoun/ . 
We can define the exact morphological class only in the context. 
In the given sentence 'half' is a pronoun. 
See some more  examples from Macmillan Dictionary:
Let’s share the prize money. 
You can have half.
The pronoun 'half' can be followed by ‘of’: 
48 is half of 96.
Half of us are still unemployed.
Also it can be followed by ‘in’ or ‘by’:
Cut the apple in half.
The crime rate has been reduced by half.

Comment: Fractions are nouns, as evident from the fact that they can  take determiners and have plural forms, which pronouns can't, as in "one half", "three quarters" and so on.